# Front Panel driver on windows 7 used the third part driver

Tags: serial-port, kmdf, umdf

We alread have a front panel based on uart commuication, I want to use it to commuicate to  windows pc. The solution is use a chip covert UART to USB, chip driver on windows is virutal COM, the driver is shown in device manager and receives information from Front Panel, but it is not open source.
I want to know how can I develop a KMDF/UMDF driver to read/write the virtual COM driver to send KEY information to windows system, or let windows system recognise this is key info.

Please give me some sample code, links, documents or advice, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Serial port KMDF sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Serial-73a4564d.
Look around there for additional documentation.